# How to add regex for different optional values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, function, match

I am working on a project where I work with the regex function.

Here is my code in jsFiddle

[My own JsFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/pikitemplates/y73u5dq1/12/)

**and the HTML is here**

```
<div class="post-body">
  <a href='/'>color=(green) title=(Hello World) caption=(Hello City 2) post=(New)</a>
</div>
```

**and js is here**

```
    $(".post-body").each(function() {
        var e = $(this),
            t = e.find("a").text();
        if (t) {
            var a = t.match(/title=\(([^)]*)\)\s+caption=\(([^)]*)\)/);
            if (a) {
                var s = a[1];
                  
                0 != s && e.find("a").text(s), 0 != i && e.find("a").text(i)
            }
        }
 });
```

This code works fine but when I put **color** and **post** values then the code stops working.

I don't know why are all values not showing like `My World Hello City 2 New`?

Here below when I tried to put values then code doesn't work, I also want that there should be optional so that we can use either use one value or all values like just use of two values  **title** and **caption** in this case, or we can use all values like `color=(green) title=(Hello World) caption=(Hello City 2) post=(New)`

```
    $(".post-body").each(function() {
         var e = $(this),
                t = e.find("a").text();
            if (t) {
            var a = t.match(/title=\(([^)]*)\)\s+caption=\(([^)]*)\)\s+post=\(([^)]*)\)\s+color=\(([^)]*)\)\s+content=\(([^)]*)\)\s+size=\(([^)]*)\)/);
            if (a) {
                var s = a[1],
                    i = a[2];
                    m = a[3];
                    n = a[4];
                    z = a[5];
                    y = a[6];
                0 != s && e.find("a").text(s), 0 != i && e.find("a").text(i), 0 != m && e.find("a").text(m), 0 != n && e.find("a").text(n), 0 != z && e.find("a").text(z), 0 != y && e.find("a").text(y)
            }
        }
 });
```

On research, I found a code created by someone that works fine maybe it's helpful to fix my problem

[Working JsFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/pikitemplates/z8vseLqf/1/)

But I am trying to create my own genuine code but it's not working. I hope here I will get some solution. Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Simplify your question. Remove the jquery and provide a completely vanilla simple explanation of what your input is and expected output with just javascript functions and regex.

Comment: I wouldn't use your "expert developer's" code as an example - it's clearly been obfuscated  / minimised.  No "expert" would write code like this.

Comment: Please re-check the jsFiddle file is updated now, with the original code.

Comment: `.text(txt)` will overwrite the text each time, you need `.append()`: https://jsfiddle.net/f5zcv8x3/1/

Comment: If you want your output in a specific order, then you'll need to provide an array of properties to extract and loop through them in that order.

Comment: i check jsfiddle its amazing but post=(new) this one not working and i want to append each value in different `<span> New </span>` tag like this, i already shared demo of jsfiddle in working code

Comment: TBH I'm a little confused - you have "copyright" code, but you want code supplied by us to be *exactly the same*.   There's no mention of `span` in your question, only "do the same as this... (later)...which has a span".  I suggest you provide a question giving exactly what you want and what you're stuck on (why you're unable to do it yourself).  Asking us to rewrite existing code so that it's the same, but different, makes no sense.

Comment: no no sir i just want to add span tag only please this is the last request, nothing else, i respect you and i don't want the same copyright code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240402/discussion-between-riya-875-and-freedomn-m).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to match with all existing fields into your syntax like this `/(?:([a-zA-Z]{3,})+=\(([^)]*)\))/g` and use matchAll to get all of them into an array and loop through the array like this if you want to show the results somewhere:

```js
$(".post-body").each(function() {
        var e = $(this),
            t = e.find("a").text();
        if (t) {
            var a = [...t.matchAll(/(?:([a-zA-Z]{3,})+=\(([^)]*)\))/g)];
            if (a) {
                a.map(function(item, key){
                  console.log(item)
                  let k = item[1];
                  let v = item[2];
                  
                  $("#results").append(`<span>${v}</span>`);
                });
            }
        }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-body">
<a href='/'>color=(green) title=(Hello World) caption=(Hello City 2) post=(New) title=(Hello World 3)</a>
</div>
<br />
<div id="results">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow - that was a difficult process! I whitnessed as @freedomn-m tried to *guess* what your intentions were and the way he spent a lot of time writing an answer and explaining it to you. This whole painful thing could have been avoided had you provided a clear [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). External snippets like the one on jsfiddle are of little help here. They will not work reasonably on smaller screens either (like on smartphones) and many SO users like answering questions on these devices.

Kudos and "+1" to @JoseLora for guessing what you wanted!

In the end the whole script can essentially be shortened into a one-liner (for better readabilty I split it into four lines here):

```js
document.getElementById("result").textContent=
  [...document.querySelector(".post-body a")
  .textContent.matchAll(/([a-zA-Z]{2,})\s*=\s*\(([^)]*)\)/g)]
  .map(e=>e[2]).join(" - ");
```

```html
<div class="post-body">
  <a href='/'>color=(green) title=(Hello World) caption=(Hello City 2) post=(New)</a>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

I also changed the regexp a little bit (removed a superfluous non-capturing group and added `\s*` before and after the `=` to make it more tolerant in case of any whitespace that should be ignored.